# Remove detect window size and add auto height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to implement the gallery on my web page that is seen here.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

The gallery is made so that jquery detects the windows height and creates an expanding box that spans the width below the thumbnail. The problem is that this set height cuts off the information that I am currently trying to put into the expanding preview. How could I change the code so that the box expands based off of the internal elements. (Similar to CSS auto height?) Or is there another option to allow all the information to be seen?

I attempted to do a jfiddle but it isn't working.

http://jsfiddle.net/sasmith/8FpQM/2/

```
function getWinSize() {
    winsize = { width : $window.width(), height : $window.height() };
}
```

Comment: would you clarify the question i dont get the problem.

Comment: With the current coding...the expanding box that drops down when you click the thumbnail only grows to the height of the window but when it does this it cuts off information that is added in the coding. For example in the dropdown I have an image, several thumbnails and a text description but info gets cut off depending on the size of the window size...Please check the accompanying video link                       http://we.tl/7bF00LORfR

Comment: ok i got the problem now , but your fiddle is not showing this , please upload your code to fiddle so we can find the problem.

Comment: The site as it is now can be downloaded here...I'm not sure how to get the fiddle to work.https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/808111186e4c496dc8acfd4df20fe4d320140324010640/820c51c5db571c1b4abfc93620ddf90320140324010640/08a84f

Comment: ok lemme check , hope i can help

Answer (score 0):

ok after struggling little with this css, this might not be the perfect solution , and because i dont have much time to read the whole code , just modify the following and the page should work fine afterwards as i hope .

open the basic.css file , and modify the class `.og-expander` to become :

```
.og-expander {
                position: absolute;
                background: #ddd;
                top: auto;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: left;
                height: auto !important;
                z-index:99;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
```

also add the following to the css file :

```
.og-grid li.og-expanded
            {
                height:900px !important;
            }
```

i have saved the modified files , and upload it here :
https://www.mediafire.com/?y3ihnadu343dsui

please let me know if it works correctly for you

Comment: It seems to have broke the layout =( http://we.tl/Ulx2GdsP2u I feel like a change in the javascript might be a better approach?